# Get text of TextInputLayout from MaterialDesigns in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

The basic code that I've seen in other posts don't seem to do the trick. It doesn't recognize the text saying **Unresolved reference: text**

`val name = binding.etName.text.toString()`

This is my XML where I have the etName, I have also try to put the etName id tag in the TextInputLayout just in case

````
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColorHint="#0B0B0B"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>```
````

Comment: I've also seen other posts accesing it by etName.getEditText().getText() but getEditText isn't permitted

Comment: `etName.getEditText()` wouldn't make sense because `etName` is an edit text, you should probably use textInputLayout.getEditText....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
textInputLayout.editText?.text?.toString() ?: ""
```